# The 'og:image' property

Tags: facebook

I implement share button at http://sportsk-vesti.co
in page source you can check meta tags

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://sportske-vesti.co/index.php?app=blog&kat=fudbal&vest=kidnapovan-fudbaler-olimpijakosa-u-meksiku" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Kidnapovan fudbaler Olimpijakosa u Meksiku" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Meksički reprezentativac i fudbalska zvezda Alan Pulido kidnapovan je u saveznoj državi Tamaulipas" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.zurnal.rs/public/uploads/article/alan-pulido.jpg" />
```

But when i want to share article, i have problem...

also, i check facebook developers link

i do not have solution

From the other side, some other article work fine :)

Little wired  for me ....
How to solve this (i read other topic, i create space in meta parts, ... )

Where is the problem ?

Comment: If you plug your website into the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) you can see that it won't pick up the `og:image` tag - I can't see anything obviously wrong though.

Comment: I try that, but no solution ?
all meta link is correct when i look page source

Answer (score 0):

The [Facebook debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) has a cache mechanism which means it wont update until you provide it with a new URL. You can append your URL with `fbrefresh=anything` in order to get new data for that URL.

When you do this it display the error that you're having:

`Provided og:image URL, http://www.zurnal.rs/public/uploads/article/alan-pulido.jpg could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb.`

Your image is too large!

Matt

Comment: @DnevneVestiFudbal Hi, [that warning appears to be a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1626463061012181/). However, it does look like the image is now scraping correctly. Are you still having an issue?

Comment: Maby FB have problem, this article now have correct image and description, but some other article not. For example:
http://sportske-vesti.co/index.php?app=blog&kat=fudbal&vest=da-li-je-ovo-novi-filip-stojkovic

Maby is problem in UTF-8 character in og meta ?

Comment: Fb have problem i think:

Time Scraped 1. јануар 1970. у 01:00

But i am confused... i do not met fb share with no image and text on other web pages...